# How do you get or retrieve data from specific row in mysql database to a textbox?

Tags: c#, mysql, get

I have codes of getting all the datas from mysql to datagrid view but I am stuck in getting data from mysql to the textbox. This textbox has read only property it is where the username of the login user will be displayed.

For further understanding here is the image.

[image: click image]

Here is my code on getting mysql database to datagridview.

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a = new ApareceCrudLib("localhost", "root", "", "cashieringdb");
            loadDataGridView_Main();
        }
        public void loadDataGridView_Main()
        {
            dgvMain.Rows.Clear();
            List<string>[] detailList = a.mysqlSelect("Select * From sales");
            for (int i = 0; i < detailList.Length; i++)
            {
                dgvMain.Rows.Add(detailList[i][0], detailList[i][1], detailList[i][2], detailList[i][3]);
            }
        }
```

This is a personal program I do this for the business of my sister. Actually my plan is to display first the Login User example "Admin123" then I will insert the data "Admin123" to Data Grid view user which is the current user at the time they log in so basically if Admin456 will login then his name will be displayed on Login User textbox and User in DataGridView. ***A sort of monitoring the login activity of different user who login.***

Comment: why you need like this ?
can you plase give me more specification ?

Comment: This is a personal program I do this for the business of my sister. Actually my plan is to display first the Login User example "Admin123" then I will insert the data "Admin123" to Data Grid view user which is the current user at the time he/she log in so basically if Admin456 will login then his name will be dispalayed on Login User txtbox and User in DataGridView. A sort of monitoring the login activity of different user who login.

Answer (score 0):

From where are you assigning a value to your text box?? (Login User).  read the suitable position in your List (detailList) for username and assign it to text box (login user). and if you want to display records belongs to logged user you have to change the query to select * from sales where username=usernameYouHaveGivenInLoginPage.

thanx...